# Is there a solution to self reference with CTE with no JOIN or UNION? Like on Manager-Employee problem

Tags: sql, oracle

Got a challenge to solve based on the classic managers-employees on the same table problem. Given a table with ids, employees and managersid

Table:

```
  EMPNO ENAME      JOB            MGR
 ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT     
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839
  7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698
  7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698
  7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566
  7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788
  7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782
```

The far that I've gone was to query using an old form of join (which I don't want) that comes after 'FROM' separated by commas:

```
WITH e AS ( SELECT * FROM employee ), 
     m AS ( SELECT * FROM employee )
SELECT e.ENAME      
    e.JOB         
    m.ENAME      
    m.JOB
FROM e,m //dont want this
WHERE e.MGR = m.EMPNO;
```

I expect a solution using CTEs without JOINS and if possible without UNION as well that gets me the output:

```
Employee   Emp# Manager Mgr# 
   BLAKE   7698 KING    7839 
   CLARK   7782 KING    7839 
   JONES   7566 KING    7839 
   MARTIN  7654 BLAKE   7698 
   ALLEN   7499 BLAKE   7698 
   TURNER  7844 BLAKE   7698 
   JAMES   7900 BLAKE   7698 
   WARD    7521 BLAKE   7698 
   FORD    7902 JONES   7566 
   SMITH   7369 FORD    7902 
   SCOTT   7788 JONES   7566 
   ADAMS   7876 SCOTT   7788 
   MILLER  7934 CLARK   7782
```

Comment: In your `WITH` above, you only need to define the `SELECT * FROM employee` one time, and reference the same `cte` in your query below using different aliases: `WITH cte AS (...) SELECT ... FROM cte AS e, cte AS m`

Comment: "I  expect a solution using CTEs without JOINS etc." - OK, but - why? You're going to use something less than optimal to produce desired result. What's the point?

Comment: @cassiobit . . . Your question does not explain what you are trying to do.  You have no question.  "Like on Manager-Employee problem" is not a question.

Comment: You can use the same table more than once in a query - there's no need to duplicate it. However, I suspect that isn't your real issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried to be brief so that I could explain better on the main text area for the question. I explained the output I want at the end.

Comment: @Littlefoot as I said, It's a challenge. Especifically from homework.

Comment: Aha. Then say that it is a "homework", not a "challenge". Anyway, it seems you got the answer. I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much more efficient using a join, but if you can't do that, then here's another way:

```sql
SELECT 
  e.ENAME, 
  e.JOB, 
  (SELECT ENAME FROM employee WHERE MGR = e.EMPNO), 
  (SELECT JOB FROM employee WHERE MGR = e.EMPNO)
FROM employee e
;
```

It has no explicit joins, but doesn't use a `CTE`.  Not sure if that's OK.

If you want with `CTE` here's one way:

```sql
WITH e AS (SELECT * FROM Employee) 
SELECT 
  emp.ENAME, 
  emp.JOB, 
  (SELECT ENAME FROM e WHERE MGR = emp.EMPNO), 
  (SELECT JOB FROM e WHERE MGR = emp.EMPNO)
FROM employee emp
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb5fe/5)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I adapted your answer and ended up quering like below:

WITH e AS (SELECT * FROM employee where MGR is not null)
SELECT 
      e.ENAME, 
      e.JOB, 
      (SELECT m.ENAME from employee m where m.EMPNO= e.MGR),
      (SELECT m.JOB from employee m where m.EMPNO= e.MGR)
FROM e;

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use CTEs you have to use UNION ALL clause anyways. You may try using CONNECT BY clause as below -

```
SELECT e.ename employee, e.EMPNO as Emp#, PRIOR ENAME as Manager, PRIOR EMPNO as Mgr#
FROM employee e
WHERE MGR IS NOT NULL
START WITH MGR IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPNO = MGR
```

Comment: Hum, are you sure  UNION is needed? I ended up solving the problem with the query below:
`

WITH e AS (SELECT * FROM employee where MGR is not null)
SELECT 
      e.ENAME, 
      e.JOB, 
      (SELECT m.ENAME from employee m where m.EMPNO= e.MGR),
      (SELECT m.JOB from employee m where m.EMPNO= e.MGR)
FROM e;
`

Comment: When I said CTE, I meant Recursive CTE. The way you have used is not recursive CTE but the sub-query factoring only.